# incorrect results when using 'in' operator in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a txt file and trying to check if a certain string is present in Pandas `dataframe` using `in` clause. However It is giving me wrong results.
how do I correct it ?

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = '\t')
if 'team=knights' in df1['column1'] :
    print('found')
else :
    print('NA')
```

**file.txt**:

```
column1
{team=knights, 2022='yes'}
{team=kayak}
```

**Output**:

```
NA
```

**Expected Output**:

```
found
```

Comment: This happens for the same reason that `'team=knights'` wouldn't be found in an ordinary list like `["{team=knights, 2022='yes'}", "{team=kayak}"]`. The string you're looking for isn't any of the elements of the sequence; it's *part of* one of those elements.

Answer (score 2):

`in` in `pandas` doesn't check

```
'team=knights' in "{team=knights, 2022='yes'}"
```

but

```
'team=knights' in [ "{team=knights, 2022='yes'}", "{team=kayak}" ]
```

and this compares

```
'team=knights' == "{team=knights, 2022='yes'}"
```

and this gives `False`

---

You can filter rows using `.str.contains()` and later check if it found any row.

Minimal working code. I use `io` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and test it. But you can use filename `'file.txt'`

```
text = '''column1
{team=knights, 2022='yes'}
{team=kayak}'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep = '\t')

mask = df['column1'].str.contains('team=knights')
selected = df[ mask ]

#if any(mask):
#if any(selected):
if selected.size > 0:
    print('found')
else:    
    print('NA')

print(selected)
```

Result:

```
found
                      column1
0  {team=knights, 2022='yes'}
```